# Pyspark : incremental ETL in cloud storage from multiple files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I have about 500-700 csv files for logs to be loaded weekly. The file names are randomly generated each week. Those files are stored on google cloud storage, and the pyspark is running on google dataproc with several worker nodes.

I've created a pyspark file which basically just iterate the files and load them as is into bigquery.
I thought I willl see incremental load on bigquery table, but it seems pyspark takes the whole gz input files, merge them into dataframe, then process it at once. So I got the result after 90 minutes or so.

How can I write the pyspark code so that everytime the file read, it will be written to bigquery. The overall time might not be changed a lot, but at least how can I see data partially written to bigquery?

Below is my code.

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Node Log ETL").getOrCreate()

log_dir = "gs://some-bucket/*.csv.gz"
log_spark = spark.read.csv(log_dir, header=True)

# Write to bigquery
log_spark.write\
    .format("bigquery")\
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "some-bucket/node-logs-temp-bq")\
    .option("dataset", "somedataset")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save("node_weekly_logs")
```

Thanks

Comment: Against the spirit of spark.

Comment: You could read files one by one and loop through the write function call. I never tried to do something like that, but it may work for your case.

Comment: What do you mean against the spirit of spark? @thebluephantom

Comment: 2nd comment: I never tried to do something like that...should make you think

Comment: if there is no transform during the Spark job, why not just using bq command to run a load job and load all csv.gz files to BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery connector does not support streaming writes to BigQuery. To write results one file at a time, you would have to read and write each file separately instead of globbing them into a single DataFrame.